# SQL, foreach-loop-like INSERT based on inserted value that need to be re-selected, possible?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers, relationship

### Current condition

I have 4 tables that looks like this
[image: Example table]
With following conditions

- `DataMessages.SenderID` is a FK with `DataUser.UserID` as reference
- `Data_UserGroup.UserID` is a FK with `DataUser.UserID` as reference
- `DataMessageRecipient.RecipID` is a FK with `DataUser.UserID` as reference
- `DataMessageRecipient.DestID` is a FK with `DataUser.DestID` as reference
- `DataMessageRecipient.MssgID` is a FK with `DataMessages.ID` as reference
- `DataMessages.ID` and `DataMessageRecipient.EntryID` are `IDENTITY()` column

And this `AFTER INSERT` trigger on dbo.DataMessages table

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER OnNewQueue ON dbo.DataMessages AFTER INSERT AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @inTabs Table
    (ID INT);
    /*Part that fetch the IDENTITY() column*/
    INSERT INTO @inTabs SELECT DataMessages.ID FROM DataMessages
        INNER JOIN inserted INS ON
            INS.SenderID = DataMessages.SenderID AND
            INS.MssgID = DataMessages.MssgID AND
            INS.CreatedAt = DataMessages.CreatedAt;
    /*
        DataMessages.CreatedAt (DateTime2), DataMessages.MssgID (int) are
        ommited from the picture, but those columns AND-ed will guaranteed to
        return unique rows because a SenderID cannot have duplicate MssgID
        even more on same CreatedAt time
    */
    INSERT INTO dbo.DataMessageRecipient (MssgID, RecipID, DestID)
        SELECT 
            inTbl.ID,
            DataUser.UserID,
            DataUser.DestID 
        FROM
            @inTabs AS inTbl,
            DataUser
        WHERE
            DataUser.UserID IN
            (
                SELECT Data_UserGroup.UserID 
                FROM Data_UserGroup
                WHERE Data_UserGroup.GroupID IN
                (
                    SELECT Data_UserGroup.GroupID 
                    FROM Data_UserGroup, inserted inr
                    WHERE Data_UserGroup.UserID = inr.SenderID
                )
            );
END
```

---

### What i'm trying to achieve

What i'm trying to achieve is, foreach inserted `DataMessages`, whether it's from a single row insert or multi-row insert, insert `DataMessageRecipient`(s) with following conditions :

1. `RecipID` and `DestID` sourced from `DataUser` table, where the `DataMessages.SenderID` share the same `Data_UserGroup.GroupID`(s)
2. `MssgID` sourced from the inserted's `DataMessages.ID`, with `RecipID` related with inserted the `SenderID` based on No.1 condition
3. (Optional to the SQL) the inserted's recipient(s) cannot include its own SenderID as the RecipID

---

### The Problem

```sql
INSERT INTO dbo.DataMessages (SenderID) 
    (10)

INSERT INTO dbo.DataMessages (SenderID) 
    (-83)

INSERT INTO dbo.DataMessages (SenderID) 
    (2213)
```

Above commands/queries behave and resulted as expected, as each of them are different separate query (fulfilling requirements, with exception condition Number 3), the problem occur, when multi row `INSERT` attempted (for example, like this)

```sql
INSERT INTO dbo.DataMessages (SenderID) 
    (10), (83), (2213)
```

The expected result is, regardless single or multi row insert, foreach inserted `DataMessages`, each inserted will have 'their own' `DataMessageRecipient` entries with `RecipID` related with each inserted `SenderID` based on entries in `Data_UserGroup` where `RecipID` and `SenderID` share the same `GroupID`(s)

What currently resulted on multi row INSERT is, foreach inserted DataMessages the 'Recipient' is merged thus all the new inserted `DataMessage` will share same Recipients

#### Example

consider following data :

```
|     DataUser    |   |    Data_UserGroup  |   |   DataMessages  |
|:------:|:------:|:-:|:------:|:---------:|:-:|:----:|:--------:|
| UserID | DestID |   | UserID |  GroupID  |   |  ID  | SenderID |
|    1   |   -1   |   |    4   |     10    |   |  100 |     4    |
|    2   |   -2   |   |    5   |     10    |   |  101 |     1    |
|    3   |   -3   |   |    2   |     11    |   |  102 |     5    |
|    4   |   -4   |   |    1   |     12    |   |      |          |
|    5   |   -5   |   |    1   |     13    |   |      |          |
|    6   |   -6   |   |    3   |     13    |   |      |          |
|        |        |   |    5   |     13    |   |      |          |
|        |        |   |    6   |     13    |   |      |          |
```

regardless the `INSERT`'s 'ways', it should have resulted with this DataMessageRecipient

```
| EntryID | MssgID | RecipID | DestID |
|:-------:|:------:|:-------:|:------:|
|         |   100  |    4    |   -4   |
|         |   100  |    5    |   -5   |
|         |   101  |    1    |   -1   |
|         |   101  |    3    |   -3   |
|         |   101  |    5    |   -5   |
|         |   102  |    5    |   -5   |
|         |   102  |    4    |   -4   |
|         |   102  |    1    |   -1   |
|         |   102  |    3    |   -3   |

/*
 Note The RecipID is STILL included as the recipients.
 This is 'okay' for now, as the logic 
 outside SQL can filter this out
*/
```

but instead, if DataMessage is inserted with multi row `INSERT`, it will resulted with result like this :

```
| EntryID | MssgID | RecipID | DestID |
|:-------:|:------:|:-------:|:------:|
|         |   101  |    1    |   -1   |
|         |   101  |    3    |   -3   |
|         |   101  |    4    |   -4   |
|         |   101  |    5    |   -5   |
|         |   102  |    1    |   -1   |
|         |   102  |    3    |   -3   |
|         |   102  |    4    |   -4   |
|         |   102  |    5    |   -5   |
|         |   103  |    1    |   -1   |
|         |   103  |    3    |   -3   |
|         |   103  |    4    |   -4   |
|         |   103  |    5    |   -5   |
```

---

### The question(s)

How can i achieve the expected result ? is this possible to do such things inside the SQL logic ? or should i pull the inserted DataMessages result and post-process it in the backend logic where i can do for-each loop foreach inserted's ID ?

Thank you

Comment: `FROM @inTabs AS inTbl, DataUser` are you intentionally using an old style `CROSS JOIN` here?

Comment: @Larnu, i think not that intentional, because on normal `JOIN` without `ON` my SQL Studio keeps throwing red-underline error and reading from Stackoverflows Q&A a 'simple' way to slaps two SELECT result without correlation whatsoever is with `CROSS JOIN`

Comment: @Larnu, and it works when the case is single row insert, so . . . i don't know if this is intentional or i it's me that just don't know if this is an 'old style'

Comment: to get the last inserted identity value within scope try scope_identity(). you can set a var declare @scope_identity int = scope_identity() and use that var to insert into your other table.

Comment: @JBJ. Yes i know i can use scope_identity(), but in event of multiple rows `INSERT` through single command/query (as far as i know) scope_identity() only gives you the last inserted row's Identity. That's why i opt to manually `SELECT` the ' inserted's ' IDs

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it. Images of the database schema rarely help. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: the only way I can think of to do this is with a trigger, you'd have to have a place to store the data but it'd get all the inserted.id's you want

Answer (score 0):

trigger can access inserted, pulling ids of whatever inserted

```
create trigger theTriggerName 
    on dbo.DataMessages for update
as
insert into dbo.DataMessagesInserted (insertedID)
select ID from inserted
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get this behaviour is that your innermost query:

```
SELECT Data_UserGroup.GroupID 
FROM Data_UserGroup, inserted inr
WHERE Data_UserGroup.UserID = inr.SenderID
```

returns ALL GroupIDs applicable at your insert.

Thus, when you do a single insert it works, but when you insert multiple, you get the groups of all rows, and for each DataMessage you will get as many rows as there are rows within Data_UserGroup containing ANY GroupID that corresponded to your query.

Also: why use a gimmick to get the identity column? The INSERTED table has this column too.

Here is my proposition:

(no insert @inTabs needed at all)

```
insert into dbo.DataMessageRecipient (MssgID, RecipID, DestID)
    select
        ins.ID as MssgID
        ,g2.UserID as RecipID
        ,u.DestID as DestID
    from
        inserted ins
        inner join Data_UserGroup g on ins.SenderID=g.UserID -- first join to get the groupID
        inner join Data_UserGroup g2 on g2.GroupID=g1.GroupID -- again join to get all userids of this groupid
        inner join DataUser u on g2.UserID=u.UserID -- to get destID
```

Also, if you want to omit the original userId, you may add in the end:

`where ins.SenderID<>g2.UserID`